# Find an $x$ such that mutually exclusive events are to disjoint sets what independent events are to $x$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, terminology

To state a matter of fact, probability theory has its own terms corresponding to proper math objects. Just out of curiosity, as disjoint sets would be called mutually exclusive events in probability theory in a suitable setting, I wonder, set-theoretically or measure-theoretically, under what name(s) are independent events?

Comment: Sets $A,B$ with $|(A\cap B)\times U|= |A\times B|$ for some universal set $U$ ... doesn't sound like a nice concept outside of probability theory

Answer (score 0):

In pure set theoretic terms, there is no notion of *measure*, so it is difficult to talk about events being independent. Disjoint events are those with no overlap, and you don't need a notion of measure to say that two sets have no elements in common.

To capture the notion of independence, we would have to say that the proportion of set $A$ that overlaps with set $B$ is the same as the proportion of the universal set that set $B$ occupies. In pure set theory, there's not really any need for talking about sets in this way, unless we're doing probability.

Comment: Thanks. I did not intend to be that restrictive :) I am interested in also a measure-theoretic name; was typing in a rush. Question revised to include measure-theoretic case now.

Comment: Well, as far as I know there isn't one. Maybe someone will answer and I'll find out otherwise. In measure theoretic terms, you could write the equation $m(A\cap B)/m(A) = m(B)/m(U)$